# Azure SQL DB - How to create new login, user with restricted access?

Tags: authentication, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure SQL DB `database1` with following schemas and objects:
`sch1.tbl1`
`sch1.tbl2`
`sch2.tbl3`
`sch2.tbl4`
`sch3.view1`
`sch3.view2`

Now, I need to create two users.

1. New login, new user with **read-write** access, only to the tables `sch1.tbl1`
   `sch1.tbl2`
   `sch2.tbl3` (i.e., select tables from different schemas).
2. New login, new user with **read-only** access, only to the views `sch3.view1`
   `sch3.view2`.

Kindly help me with the commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the below queries in Master database:

```
create login [login] with password = ‘<<>>’
```

Then execute the below queries in actual database:

```
create user [login] from login [login]

Grant Select ON sch.table1 TO [login] --Read
```

Replace Select key word with Insert, Update and Delete on the above Read query for write access on the tables

Comment: Thanks, Nandan.

It works with an additional line.

In Master database:

`CREATE LOGIN usertest WITH PASSWORD = 'mypassword' 
GO

CREATE USER usertest FROM LOGIN usertest
GO`

In actual database:

`CREATE USER usertest FROM LOGIN usertest
GO

Grant Select ON sch1.table1 TO usertest
GO`